# JPA do not insert in database, why?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

i'm new with JPA, i'm using in a JSF 2 Project with Glassfish 3 and Eclipse Java EE Web Developers.
These are my settings and the way that I'm trying to persist in my database:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SuaParte" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.suaparte.pojo.Area</class>
            //other entities

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/sua_parte"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=<username>/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=<password>/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="area")
public class Area implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private byte id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=45)
    private String area;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Company
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="areaBean")
    private List<Company> companies;

    //getters and setters    


}
```

And how i'm calling my EntityManager and try to persist the object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SuaParte");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Area area = new Area();
    area.setArea("test");

    entityManager.persist(area);

}
```

But when i execute nothing happens in my database, JPA do not persist the object in my table, what i'm doing wrong ?
Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack [transaction handling](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions), e.g.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(area);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I recommend you read up on JPA and JSF integration, there might be some utility/filter/JSF support that takes care of this for you.

Comment: If you finally end up implementing it in JSF, do it in an EJB, then transactions will be handled for you by the container.